# how to concatenate variable with the path in ansible script

Tags: python, windows, ansible

I have created an Ansible script to download PuTTY and install it on Windows.

```
- hosts: windows
  tasks:
     - name: Download Zip File
       win_get_url:
         url: "{{zipurl}}"
         dest: "{{myvarfile}}"
     - name: Extract zipfile
       win_unzip:
         src: "{{myvarfile}}"
         dest: "C:\{{packagename}}"
         recurse: yes
         rm: true
```

Then:

```
ansible-playbook deploywar.yml \
  --extra-vars="myvarfile=c:\putty.zip zipurl=https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/w64/putty.zip packagename=putty"
```

now i need to pass the package name as parameter and need to concatenate in:

```
dest: "C:\\{{packagename}}"
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try a double backslash.

Answer (score 1):

Either use single quotes:

```
dest: 'C:\{{packagename}}'
```

or escape special characters:

```
dest: "C:\\{{packagename}}"
```